# How can characters be escaped in programmatic search in Word Add-ins?

Tags: ms-word, office-addins, office-js

Let's say my code in a Word Web Add-in needs to find strings that consist of a pair of [], with any number of characters between them, followed by a pair of () with any number of characters between them. Since the [,],(, and ) are special characters in RegEx (which Word calls "wildcard search" in its UI), they need to be escaped. The following works fine when I do a wildcard search in the UI:

```
\[*\]\(*\)
```

But when I'm using one of the search() functions in Office.js, such as this:

```
var searchResults = context.document.body.search('\[*\]\(*\)');
```

I get only the ranges that consist of a single "*" character.

So, how do I escape characters programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question under new stackexchange ID.

The backslash character, "\" is not used as the escape character in programmatic search. To escape a character in the search() function, you wrap it in "[]" characters. The following is the programmatic equivalent of the UI search string I used in the question:

```
[[]*[]][(]*[)]
```

This works just fine.